# Ghost CMS - Keeping images at their default size

Tags: markdown, ghost-blog, ghost

I've just switched from Wordpress to Ghost. Loving it so far, but one big issue I'm having is resizing images.

I'm using the default theme, and some of the images are small. When I add them into a post they stretch 100% of the width. The markdown I'm using is:

```
![Alt Text](http://example.com/image.png)
```

I don't insert the URL for the image as I am uploading it.

Is there any way to resize the images, or keep them at their original size without having them span 100%?

Comment: This is a problem that is best addressed at the theme level by simply removing the `width: 100%` CSS on images. If you post the theme you are using we may be able to give a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using markdown but you can use the `img` html tag.

First, you have to upload your image: [Upload images on Ghost](https://help.ghost.org/hc/en-us/articles/223237408-Upload-Images)

And then, replace the markdown code `![Alt](my-image.png)` with the HTML tag  `<img alt="Alt" src="my-image.png" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" />`

Comment: I downvoted your answer, William. When I tried your suggestion the blog printed the tag as text. If you in future change your answer, let me know. I will change my vote.

Comment: @zatziky Not sure why it doesn't work for you, but this works without any issue for me (using 1.22.8)

Comment: @chintogtokh Our version is 1.22.7. Obviously, I am the one who made the mistake so I'm removing my downvote. Thank you!